# Inserting multiple tick boxes into one database field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

as the question says, I am trying to insert one or more tick box values into one database field, preferably in a comma delimited format.

So if the user chooses tick box one and tick box two, the input into the database will be inserted as tickOne, tickTwo, etc etc

How could I go about doing that?
Maybe using jQuery or Javascript?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: 1) Not enough detail. 2) Denormalization like this is bad, don't do it.

Comment: @RedFilter - If the values are just for UI display, denormalization may not be bad, it may be much more efficient...you can't say blanketly that it's bad, you need more info to make that decision, e.g. will it ever be queried?

Comment: @RedFilter, what if it's a simple CRM he's building that is a contact form manager. Denormalization isn't always a bad thing.

Comment: How would you recommend I get the data into the database?

Creating a bunch of fields for each input box just doesn't seem efficient at all!

Comment: @Nick Craver - if it will never be queried, then no point persisting it.

Comment: @Mike Sherov - where did I say denormalization is always bad?

Comment: @Red - sure there is, grabbing it for *display* isn't the same as using it in a where clause, which is what I meant by queuing *that* particular piece of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass the values as a string, say comma delimited like you mentioned in jquery you could set the value using [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), like this:

```
$(".mySelector:checkbox").change(function() {
  var values = $(".mySelector:checkbox:checked").map(function() {
                 return this.value;
               }).get().join(', ');
  $("#myHiddenInput").val(values);
});
```

Every time a checkbox changes, it'll re-do the string portion, re-serializing the result, so on postback it should be the current UI selection.  [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) gets an array of the values of the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) elements with your `mySelector` class, then we're just doing a [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/join) to convert that array into a string and using [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the hidden input for this to that string.

This assumes markup like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="mySelector" value="tickOne" />
<input type="checkbox" class="mySelector" value="tickTwo" />
....
<input type="hidden" id="myHiddenInput" />
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/pXTQU/)

Comment: so I should create a hidden input field and then once the user has selected the tick boxes they will be assigned to the hidden input fields value?

Comment: @kielie - Yup, if you want to do it client-side something like that...I added a demo/example markup to better illustrate it :)

Comment: How can I limit the amount of boxes ticked to 3?

Comment: @kielie - add a :lt(3) after the :checked (no spaces) to get the first 3 only :)

Comment: Thanx that worked, is there a way to disable the rest of the check boxes once the limit is reached? sorry to be a bother!